# Clipping Raster with output using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: raster, arcgis-pro, clip

[image]

I'm trying to clip an elevation contour raster layer to the extent of the site boundaries. In the output raster layer the pixels seem to have increased in size a lot and the new layer looks nothing like the original.

I changed the sampling method to bilinear interpolation with no effect. I compared the raster information to the original contour layer and the cell size is the same. The only difference between the two was the pyramid level. 8 levels in the original and only 1 in the output. I tried specifying 8 pyramid levels and that also had no effect.

Comment: What data type output have you selected? Maybe you are decreasing bit size. Although without sample files is gonna be hard to find a reliable solution

Comment: What's an "elevation contour raster"? Usually contours are a *vector* product. Pixels are always created in the size you request, even if you don't know you're requesting them that way.